# PowerShell .ps1 script file is deleted when run from CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

When I execute a powershell script file from **`Command Prompt Window`**, the file just disappears.  The CMD window does not show any error messages, it just goes to the next line immediately after executing the command.  I restore the file from a backup.

When I execute the powershell script file from **`Power Shell Window`**, the process completes successfully.

I initially noticed the file had disappeared when I tried to using the **`Execute Process Task in SSIS`**, as seen in the posted on [SQL Server Central: execute+process+task](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/execute+process+task/129996/) and [MSDN Blog Article: run-powershell-scripts-in-ssis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/01/26/run-powershell-scripts-in-ssis/).

***What is causing the file to disappear?***

The .PS1 file refreshes an excel file with data connections and saves the file.

---

**Power Shell, commands tested (only the first one fails, the other 3 work)**

```
PS H:\> "PowerShell.exe" "-F C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1"
Unexpected token '-F C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1' in expression
 statement.
At line:1 char:103
+ "PowerShell.exe" "-F C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1" <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-F C:\SVN\Busin...xcelRefresh.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS H:\> powershell -noexit C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1
PS H:\> PowerShell.exe -F C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1
PS H:\> PowerShell.exe -File C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1
PS H:\>
```

**Command Prompt, commands tested (file disapears)**

```
PowerShell.exe -File C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1
```

**PowerShell_Exec_FileDisappears.png**

[image]

Comment: This is (naturally) not normal behavior. It must have to do something with what happens in the script. We cannot tell without seeing it. Maybe your anti virus software deletes it?

Comment: @marsze - How could it be the script?  The *scripts* runs fine when the lines are entered manually in Powershell.  The *PS1 script file* execution works just fine when ran via powershell.  The *PS1 script file* execution when ran via command line is the only issue... the file gets deleted.  Thanks for your idea about anti virus; Is there some way I can look into that possibility?  Our org uses Kaspersky for anti virus.

Comment: It's very simple to verify: Have you tried changing the script's contents to something simple like an echo command and then try it again? I suppose it should not be deleted then. You can use that technique to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @marsze - Based on your suggestion I changed the file to contain only one line: `Write-Host "Hello, World!"`.  Ran the script file via command the line, and still the file gets deleted. When ran via powershell, the text "Hello, World!" is displayed.  So, it seems to still be an issue with CMD Window only.  But why?

Comment: Have you tried other script names / paths etc.? Try to narrow down the problem. I cannot really help since I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @marsze - Well, this is really weird.  Created a new file in a different directory ' C:\Users\bl0040\Documents\PoSH-SimpleFile.ps1' with the same simple script 'Write-Host "Hello, World!'.  It executed from CMD just fine.  I copied that file to the same folder and renamed it back to the former name 'DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1', then executed it from CMD and the file was erased.  This is a new directory with the same filename.

Comment: I can reproduce it now. It seems to be related to the dot in the file name (from ".xlsx"). Funny, if you remove the dot, it works. Even funnier: If you replace ".xlsx" with ".ps1" *inside* the file name, it works too. This seems almost like a bug in PowerShell or CMD. I will investigate it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more than weird. I was able to reproduce it. But I cannot explain why this happens. My guess is, this is somehow an optimization bug in the parsing of paths when calling PowerShell to run a script. You even have the same issue when calling it from *inside* PowerShell, when calling it like this for example:

```
. "powershell.exe" -File C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1
# or
Start-Process "powershell" -Arg "-File", "C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1"
```

I can give you some pointers what alternatives should work though:

**Easiest: Remove or replace the dot!**

```
powershell -File "C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats_xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1"
```

**Alternatively, these variations should also work:**

```
# Pass a command which calls the script using the call operator (&)
# Note: The single quotes are necessary! Else you will have the same behavior
powershell -Command "& 'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1'"

# A workaround to avoid the issue that's probably causing this.
# The semicolon basically puts an empty command at the beginning.
# This supports my theory, that this is somehow an optimization bug.
powershell -Command ";& C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1"

# Base64-encoded version of
# "& C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1"
powershell -EncodedCommand "JgAgAEMAOgBcAFMAVgBOAFwAQgB1AHMAaQBuAGUAcwBzAEEAbgBhAGwAeQBzAHQAcwBcAEUAeABjAGUAbABUAG8AbwBsAHMAXABEAGEAdABhAGIAYQBzAGUAUwBTAEEAUwBfAFUAcwBhAGcAZQBTAHQAYQB0AHMALgB4AGwAcwB4AF8ARQB4AGMAZQBsAFIAZQBmAHIAZQBzAGgALgBwAHMAMQA="
```

I wrote some feedback to Microsoft about this, but I recommend you investigate this further and maybe write a bug report to the PowerShell team.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm been silly, but I had a similar issue.

In my case the Kaspersky antivirus was removing the script to quarentine. Same thing had happen with pre-installed McAfee in another computer.

In both situations I was able to solve it by adding the PowerShell Scripts as a 'trusted application'.

The line that was triggering the antivirus was:

```
    Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList ('-File', $PSCommandPath, '-NoExit', '-NoProfile') -Verb Runas
```

At first I didn't notice the [Kaspersky's notifications.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVypQ.jpg)

Then I tried register the script as a exclusion but didn't work as I was expecting. So Kaspersky start [asking for desinfect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ38h.jpg)

Comment: Somehow -NoExit flag raises this problem. It works if I remove it.